# RegSetValueEx - wrong path, 64bit, running as admin

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, registry

I have some questions related to registry related functions.
I used RegSetValueEx function to create a registry data but unfortunately I did it wrong for sure but I am not sure, where the mistake is. I want to create a registry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE - SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run but it creates the data only in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key and that's all.

```
TCHAR name[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
GetUserName((TCHAR*)name, &size);
string namep = name;
string path = "C:\\Users\\" + namep + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\MyProgram\\MyProgram.exe";
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    cout << "OPENED!";
    if (RegQueryValueEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "MyRegistry", 0, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        cout << "NOT FOUND!"; // If registry not found, then create it?
        if (RegSetValueEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "MyRegistry", 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)path.c_str(), path.size()) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            cout << "REGISTRY WRITTEN";
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
}
```

Ok, so that's the code, what is wrong?
Also I would like to ask how to do it, so I don't have to run it as admin to make it create the registry because if I don't run it as admin, it won't create the registry.
And how is it with 64bit versions of OS? I compile on 32bit, so is there anything that I have to do so it works on 64bit machines?

Thanks. =)

Comment: I recommend using wide strings instead of `TCHAR` to pass into winapi functions. You're assuming `TCHAR` is `char` when calling the functions, too, which defeats the purpose.

Comment: The documentation says *cbData must include the size of the terminating null character or characters.* for `RegSetValueEx`.

Comment: The data is saved correctly o.0 but the thing is that its path is not correct. I am going to try the thing with wide strings.

Comment: Wide strings won't make a difference if you're passing ANSI data, but you basically have three choices, with `TCHAR` implying twice as many builds of the project and ANSI not supporting the vast majority of characters. I consider `TCHAR` more work in the code as well, and ANSI vs. Unicode to be equal there, so why not pick the better one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.

First, do not hard-code file paths, especially paths that include system folders.  In this case, you should use `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_APPDATA)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData)` to discover the location of the current user's `AppData\Roaming` folder.  Or, if `MyProgram.exe` is the app that is currently running, you could use `GetModuleFileName(0)` instead.

Second, a non-admin user does not have write access to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, only to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.  If you need to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, your app needs to run with elevated admin privileges.

Third, you are not using `RegQueryValueEx()` and `RegSetValueEx()` correctly.  Specifically:

1. you are passing the wrong `HKEY` in the first parameter. You need to pass the `HKEY` that `RegOpenKeyEx()` returned to you.
2. for `RegSetValueEx()`, a `REG_SZ` value must include the null terminator, however `path.size()` does not count the null terminator, so you need to use `size()+1` instead.

Fourth, you are leaking the `HKEY` that `RegOpenKeyEx()` returned to you, since you are calling `RegCloseKey()` only if `RegQueryValueEx()` succeeds.

With all of that said, try something more like this:

```
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    cout << "OPENED! ";

    LONG lRet = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, TEXT("MyRegistry"), 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (lRet == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
    {
        cout << "NOT FOUND! ";

        // assuming you want to store the calling process's
        // filename, otherwise adjust this as needed ...
        TCHAR filename[MAX_PATH + 1];
        DWORD len = GetModuleFileName(NULL, filename, MAX_PATH);
        filename[len] = 0;

        if (RegSetValueEx(hKey, TEXT("MyRegistry"), 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)filename, (len+1) * sizeof(TCHAR)) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            cout << "WRITTEN!";
        else
            cout << "NOT WRITTEN!";
    }
    else if (lRet == 0)
    {
        cout << "FOUND!";
    }
    else
        cout << "NOT QUERIED!";

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
else
    cout << "NOT OPENED!";
```

If you just want to make sure the Registry contains the latest filename, you can omit `RegQueryValueEx()` and let `RegSetValueEx()` overwrite an existing value, if present:

```
if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    cout << "OPENED! ";

    // assuming you want to store the calling process's
    // filename, otherwise adjust this as needed ...
    TCHAR filename[MAX_PATH + 1];
    DWORD len = GetModuleFileName(NULL, filename, MAX_PATH);
    filename[len] = 0;

    if (RegSetValueEx(hKey, TEXT("MyRegistry"), 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)filename, (len+1) * sizeof(TCHAR)) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        cout << "WRITTEN!";
    else
        cout << "NOT WRITTEN!";

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
else
    cout << "NOT OPENED!";
```

Comment: Alright, I think you answered my questions. Thank you! =)
Oh, one more question remained unaswered. How is it with 64bit machines? Is there anything to avoid or do to make it work on 64bit machines when I compile on 32bit machine?

Comment: *Compiling* it on a 32bit machine and *running* it on a 64bit machine does not make any difference. What matters is whether it is *compiled* as a 32bit or 64bit executable (a 32bit machine can compile a 64bit executable). That does affect how certain areas of the Registry are accessed, when running a 32bit executable on a 64bit machine via the WOW64 emulator. See MSDN: [Registry Redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Very Good. Thank you)